# Unity.Configuration Issue while migrating from VS 2013 to 2015

Tags: unity-container

While migrating from VS 2013 to 2015. I started getting run time error of Unity.Configuration - The type name or alias XXXX could not be resolved. Please check your configuration file and verify this type name."}

I tried below few options in configuration file but it didn't help

```
 <alias alias="XXXX" type="namespace.XXXX,  assembly_name" />
 <namespace name="namespace" />
 <assembly name="assembly_name" />
 <typeAlias alias="XXXX" type="namespace.XXXX,  assembly_name" />
```

Comment: Maybe it's among the answers for [resolving that message in general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668240/unity-3-and-error-the-type-name-or-alias-xxxxx-could-not-be-resolved-please)?

Comment: Thanks Stein, I already went through this link and tried few option but it didn't work in my case.